# Need Simple C# Game Engine/Library for Simulation

Tags: c#

I need a simple game engine for making a simulation. I want to make a simulation you cannot interact with, but will let a little mini world play out, with animals and men.
All I need in this game engine/library is:
*1: Simple C# programming so I can mass generate the world*
*2: Displaying simple 3D graphics*
*3: The ability to code a camera that can you can steer/drag through the world*
*4: Gravity*
*5: Colliders*

I have tried:
 
Unity, but it is too restricting and only supports .NET 2.0.
Veldrid, but it has lousy documentation and no tutorials.
SlimDX, but I could find no more tutorials/documentation after the ones from they're tutorial page
SharpGL, but like Veldrid, lousy documentation and no tutorials.

Do any of you know any game engines/libraries I could use?

Comment: As far as I know, you have to use unity and import it using Swapchainpanel in XAML UWP. Or OPENGL using cpp